# How to create an array from serial.read?

Tags: serial, array

I'm working on a audio-reactive lightinstallation with 16 LED lights.
In Max MSP I analyse my audio and split the frequencies in 16 'parts'.
I store these parts in a message of 16 ints, either 1 or 0 (on of off).
Every time a new frequency is detected the message updates and puts out a new int from 16 numbers (for exampe 1000100100110101).

I receive this number in my serial monitor of my Arduino Uno.
I want to put this 'incomingValues' in an array so I can check if a number/frequency is 0 or 1. When it's 1 I can turn on my relay/ light.
The 'incomingValues' is changing quite quickly but that shouldn't be a problem right?

I tried multiple things to create an array and update this every time a new serial message is coming in but I'm not used to work with Arduino so I could need some help.

Thanks! :)

Here is my code:

```
int counter;
int incomingValues = 0;
int lights[16];


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  counter = 0;
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  boolean newValue = false;

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    incomingValues = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(incomingValues);
    counter = counter + 1;

    newValue = true;
  }


  if (newValue) {
//    delay(50);
//    lights[counter] = incomingValues;
//
//
//    Serial.print(lights[0]);
//
//    for (int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i ++) {
//      Serial.print(lights[i]);
//    }
//    Serial.println("");
//    newValue = false;
  }

  if (counter > 15) {
    counter = 0;
    Serial.print("\n");
  }

  if (incomingValues == 1) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  } else if (incomingValues == 0) {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: so, what is the problem?

Comment: You already save the data in the lights array (if you uncomment the newvalue if statement). Where exactly do you need help? What doesn't work as how you indended and what does it actally does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to send the message as 16 chars, followed by a newline, then here is a test sketch that might work for you. Use the Serial Monitor to send the `1000100100110101` data. Please ensure you have the Serial Monitor set to send a `Newline Only`.

```cpp
// Valid input data from serial is 16 chars followed by a newline.
// 1000100100110101
const byte bufferSize = 17;
char inputBuffer[bufferSize + 1];

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    byte bytesRead = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', inputBuffer, bufferSize);
    if(bytesRead == 16){
      for(byte i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        if(inputBuffer[i] == '1'){
          Serial.print("on ");
        }
        else{
          Serial.print("off ");
        }
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Invalid data length.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @VE7JRO, it does the job :)

```
const byte bufferSize = 16;
char inputBuffer[bufferSize + 1];
int myDelay = 20;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){

  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    byte bytesRead = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', inputBuffer, bufferSize);
    if(bytesRead == 16){
      for(byte i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        if(inputBuffer[0] == 1){
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
          delay(myDelay);
        }
        else{
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        }
        if(inputBuffer[1] == 1){
          digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
          delay(myDelay);
        }
        else{
          digitalWrite(12, LOW);
        }
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Invalid data length.");
    }
  }
}
```